# How do I bind an event handler a leaflet DivOverlay so that I can resize the table inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a leaflet DivOverlay that I'm trying to bind an event handler to. More specifically a 'resize' event handler. I have tried binding using javascript:

```
$(this._container).on('resize', this._onResize)
```

And I know the container is already present on the page because it works fine with a click handler:

```
$(this._container).on('click', this._onResize)
```

I have also tried:

```
L.DomEvent.on(this._container, 'resize', this._onResize, this);
```

but, it seems DomEvent doesn't like 'resize', it works with 'click' though.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, I realize that I cannot bind a resize event to anything other than the window object, what's the best alternative for handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it seems that I have to use a plugin to handle element resizing. Why in the world resize events only fire on window resizing is beyond me.